# Contour plot adding lines

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to add a horizontal line at `y=1` and a vertical line at `x=1` to my contour plot, how do I do this?

My code looks the following way:

```
library(plotly)
library("mvtnorm")

cov=matrix(c(2,1,1,2),2,2)

x1=seq(-4,4,by=0.1)
x2=seq(-4,4,by=0.1)

d<-expand.grid(x1,x2)

z=dmvnorm(as.matrix(d),sigma=cov)

plot_ly(x=d[,1],y=d[,2],z=z,type="contour")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
plot_ly(x = d[, 1], y = d[, 2], z = ~z, type = "contour") %>%
  add_segments(x = 1, xend = 1, y = -4, yend = 4, inherit = FALSE) %>%
  add_segments(x = -4, xend = 4, y = 1, yend = 1, inherit = FALSE) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(range = c(-4, 4)),
         yaxis = list(range = c(-4, 4)))
```

[image]

where I added `inherit = FALSE` to avoid warnings, and the `layout` part to fix the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibility for this.

The first one is with `add_segments` the other one is with `layout`:

1. with add_segments

   ```
   plot_ly(x=d[,1],y=d[,2],z=z,type="contour")%>%
       add_segments(x = 0, xend = 0, y = -4, yend = 4)%>%
       add_segments(x = -4, xend = 4, y = 0, yend = 0)
   ```
2. with layout:

   ```
   plot_ly(x=d[,1],y=d[,2],z=z,type="contour")%>%
       layout(shapes=list(type="line", x0=0, x1=0, y0=-4, y1=4))%>%
       layout(shapes=list(type="line", x0=-4, x1=4, y0=0, y1=0))%>
   ```

for changing colours or something similar i recommend the documentation of plot.ly